# I can't load my flutter web app which need credentials to access the url

Tags: web, fonts, credentials, manifest.json, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm getting the below error:

"Rejecting promise with error: Flutter Web engine failed to complete HTTP request to fetch "assets/FontManifest.json": TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials: assets/FontManifest.json", source: https://scanpay.ewirecards.com/main.dart.js (29840)

I have not specified FontManifest.json in assets. Apart from that, I'm using fonts from Google Fonts.

I'm using flutter version : 3.10.4. Can anyone help with this.